# Why Google glass ends activity when it goes to sleep?

Tags: android, android-activity, google-glass, google-gdk

I have started developing on Google glass but i found something very weird. Activity ends when Google glass goes to sleep? Can anyone help me on how can i stop the glass from killing the activity.

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue with a service. Have you solved this?

Comment: @Clocker well if ur facing this problem due to idle time of google glass then u can solve it by setting the activiy immersive property to true in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having a very similar issue. I also found a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318952

As noted in the comments by the poster, adding the [immersive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#immersive) property to my `AndroidManifest.xml` fixed the issue and the Glass now always wakes up to my Activity.

```xml
<activity
    android:name="com.my.app.ActivityName"
    android:immersive="true">
</activity>
```